# Add Where clause to IQueryable<T> in function?

Tags: c#, .net, where-clause, iqueryable, ref

Why **Where** clause is not applied to IQueryable in the **AddWhereToQuery** function ?

It should be reference type and I cannot see why this code should not work as I expect.

```
[Route("/testing")]
public class MyTestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly YieldigoDbContext _db;

    public MyTestController(YieldigoDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var queryable = _db.Articles.AsQueryable();
        AddWhereToQuery(queryable);

        var queryString = queryable.ToQueryString();

        return Ok(queryString);
    }

    private void AddWhereToQuery(IQueryable<Article> queryable)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Status == ArticleStatus.Active);
    }
}
```

When I add **ref** keyword it works just fine, but why ref is necessary

```
[Route("/testing")]
public class MyTestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly YieldigoDbContext _db;

    public MyTestController(YieldigoDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var queryable = _db.Articles.AsQueryable();
        AddWhereToQuery(ref queryable);

        var queryString = queryable.ToQueryString();

        return Ok(queryString);
    }

    private void AddWhereToQuery(ref IQueryable<Article> queryable)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Status == ArticleStatus.Active);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're passing by reference instead of by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Get()` method you create a variable `var queryable` which we'll call `1` that contains a reference to that instance which we'll call `A`. So `queryable` holds a reference `1->A`.

Now you call the function `AddWhereToQuery(... queryable)`. The `queryable` is a copy of your variable which we'll call `2` that points to the same reference `2->A`.

So now you create a new instance of a queryable object which we'll call `B` and you save that in your `queryable` in the scope of the function. So now `2->B`.

As you see at no point have you changed what `1` points to so the instance with your `Where` filter is never used. If you were to use `ref` it won't make a copy but will pass the variable itself (whether struct or reference type).

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code in this way:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var queryable = _db.Articles.AsQueryable();
    queryable = AddWhereToQuery(queryable);

    var queryString = queryable.ToQueryString();

    return Ok(queryString);
}

private IQueryable<Article> AddWhereToQuery(IQueryable<Article> queryable)
{
    return queryable.Where(x => x.Status == ArticleStatus.Active);
}
```